Is every value the smallest nontrivial faithful representation of some group?
We can order the irreducible characters of a group by their degree. Is it true that for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ there is a group whose second character has degree $n$? Is this a known thing?
Irreducible is a critical hypothesis, because otherwise this would be asking "is there a faithful representation into dimension $n$ for each $n$?" Which is the same as asking "is there a group or order $n$?

Is there a group whose second character has degree 2?  I don't think there is.

I haven't been able to come up with one. I can find first nonlinear is $2$. ($S_3$, other dihedral groups)

I was wrong. According to GaP, the unique perfect group of order 120 has its second character of degree 2.

If $G$ is a finite group with no nontrivial character of degree 1, then $G$ is perfect (i.e. $G'=G$, where $G'$ is the commutator group of $G$).
A (nontrivial) perfect group is nonsolvable (since nontrivial solvable groups must have $G' < G$), and therefore contains a nonabelian finite simple group as a composition factor. So it seems like to answer your question, we may have to turn to the classification of finite simple groups. I don't think it will have an easy answer.
